# Find $\theta$ and $\phi$ that maximize $\mid -2ia\sin\theta - 2ib\sin\phi + 2c(1-\cos\theta) +2d(1-\cos\phi)\mid$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, optimization, absolute-value

How can you find for what values of the $\theta$ and $\phi$ angles the following modulus will assume its greatest possible value?

$$\mid -2ia\sin(\theta) - 2ib\sin(\phi) + 2c(1-\cos(\theta)) +2d(1-\cos(\phi))\mid$$

$i$ is complex, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are free parameters. I want to find for what $\theta$ and $\phi$ this expression maximizes because I want to find the values the parameters can take to keep the modulus at less than $1$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Put ${\delta\over \delta \theta}=0$ keeping $\phi$ constant; substitute $\theta$ in terms of $\phi$ and then again ${\delta\over \delta \phi}=0$? I think this should work.

Comment: Are $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $\theta$, and $\phi$ real?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Let $z_{1}=x_{1}+y_{1}i=c(1-\cos \theta)-ai\sin \theta$, then
>
> $$\frac{(x_{1}-c)^2}{c^2}+\frac{y_{1}^2}{a^2}=\frac{c^2\cos^2 \theta}{c^2}+\frac{a^2\sin^2 \theta}{a^2}=1$$
>
> Let $z_{2}=x_{2}+y_{2}i=-d(1-\cos \phi)+bi\sin \phi$, then 
>   $$\frac{(x_{2}+d)^2}{d^2}+\frac{y_{2}^2}{b^2}=\frac{d^2\cos^2 \theta}{d^2}+\frac{b^2\sin^2 \theta}{b^2}=1$$
>
> Now your expression becomes $2|z_{1}-z_{2}|$.

Up to scaling, it's equivalent to find the maximal distance between the ellipses:

$$
\left \{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    \displaystyle \frac{(x-c)^2}{c^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2} &=& 1 \\
    \displaystyle \frac{(x+d)^2}{d^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} &=& 1
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Considering their tangents with common slope $m$:

$$
\left \{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    y &= &m(x-c) \pm \sqrt{c^2 m^2+a^2} \\
    y &= &m(x+d) \mp \sqrt{d^2 m^2+b^2}
  \end{array}
\right.$$

[image]

The distance between the two tangents is:

$$p_{\pm}=\left| \frac{\pm \sqrt{c^2 m^2+a^2}-cm \pm \sqrt{d^2 m^2+b^2}-dm}
       {\sqrt{1+m^2}} \right|$$

We can maximize $p_{\pm}$ graphically or numerically when $a,b,c,d$ are specified.

[image]

> Note that $p_{+}$ and $p_{-}$ are mirror images, just pick up the absolute maximum of $2p_{+}$.

Comment: This is beautiful, many thanks, I'll go over it in more detail as soon as I find the time!

Comment: I was wondering if you can shed some more light on how my statement is equivalent to the problem you are solving. I follow your explanation smoothly, but I can't see how the sines and cosines I have up there are related or describe ellipses. Any further explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Let $z_{1}=x_{1}+y_{1}i=c(1-\cos \theta)-a\sin \theta i$, then 
$$\frac{(x-c)^2}{c^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}=\frac{c^2\cos^2 \theta}{c^2}+\frac{a^2\sin^2 \theta}{a^2}=1$$

Let $z_{2}=x_{2}+y_{2}i=-d(1-\cos \phi)+b\sin \phi i$, then 
$$\frac{(x+d)^2}{d^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=\frac{d^2\cos^2 \theta}{d^2}+\frac{b^2\sin^2 \theta}{b^2}=1$$

Now your expression becomes $2|z_{1}-z_{2}|$

Comment: Thank you for the follow up, it really clears things up.