# Ellipse to ellipse distance

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Suppose I am given two ellipses $A$ and $B$, where centers $c_A$,$c_B$, semi-major axis $a_A$,$a_B$, semi-minor axis $b_A$,$b_B$ and counterclockwise rotations $\theta_A$,$\theta_B$  are known. How do I compute the Euclidean distance represented by the red line, e.g. the distance from the point on the ellipse of $A$ closest to $B$ to the point on the ellipse of $B$ furthest from $A$ when going straight through $c_A$ and $c_B$.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please also refer to my [*newer post*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4717254/quick-inexact-method-to-get-shortest-line-between-two-2d-ellipses/4717309#4717309) and [*older post*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851240).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll change a bit your notations, so it is easier for me to graph it in Desmos.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kwntsr3k1b

First ellipse : center $(x_0,y_0)$, axis $a,b$ and rotation $f$

$$\frac{\Big((x-x_0)\cos(f)+(y-y_0)\sin(f)\Big)^2}{a^2}+\frac{\Big((x-x_0)\sin(f)-(y-y_0)\cos(f)\Big)^2}{b^2}=1$$

Second ellipse : center $(X_0,Y_0)$, axis $A,B$ and rotation $F$

$$\frac{\Big((X-X_0)\cos(F)+(Y-Y_0)\sin(F)\Big)^2}{A^2}+\frac{\Big((X-X_0)\sin(F)-(Y-Y_0)\cos(F)\Big)^2}{B^2}=1$$

Line joining the two centers

$$\left(y-y_{0}\right)\left(x_{0}-X_{0}\right)=\left(x-x_{0}\right)\left(y_{0}-Y_{0}\right)$$

Let introduce the ratio $R=\left(\dfrac{y_{0}-Y_{0}}{x_{0}-X_{0}}\right)$, I assume here $x_0\neq X_0$, so the line is not vertical, I let you solve this case on your own.

Now you just need to solve for the four intersection points.

For instance for first ellipse set $(x-x_0)=z$ and $(y-y_0)=Rz$ and you will arrive to $$uz^2=1$$

with

$$u=\frac{\Big(\cos(f)+R\sin(f)\Big)^2}{a^2}+\frac{\Big(\sin(f)-R\cos(f)\Big)^2}{b^2}$$

Same for the other ellipse, by replacing lower case letters by upper case ones.

You get $4$ points I called $d,e,D,E$ on the graphic $\begin{cases}\text{ellipse 1}&\left(x_{0}\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}},\ y_{0}\pm\frac{R}{\sqrt{u}}\right)\\\text{ellipse 2}&\left(X_{0}\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{U}},\ Y_{0}\pm\frac{R}{\sqrt{U}}\right)\end{cases}$

It is then straightforward to calculate the distances either $\operatorname{dist}(d,D)$ or $\operatorname{dist}(e,E)$ depending on the relative position of the two ellipses.