# Quick inexact method to get shortest line between two 2d ellipses

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, conic-sections

I'm trying to find the two points that form the shortest line between two ellipses (can have different semi-major and semi-minor axes, but they are not rotated), such as the green line in the image below. I assume this line would be normal to both ellipses. The red line just connects their centers. The dashed gray line connects where the red line intersects the ellipses. This dashed gray line is longer than the green line.

I understand that finding the start and end points of the green line is mathematically complex and requires numerical techniques. Is there a simple quick method to find the start and end points of the green line if it doesn't have to be exactly the shortest? It must be better than the dashed gray line though. I don't really have a good heuristic or constraint for how inexact it can be.

My initial thought is to start with the intersection points of the red line (connect the centers of the ellipses). Then, for each ellipse, move the point toward the direction that the red line veers from the normal. The greater the angle between the red line and the normal, move the point further.

[image: Two ellipses and lines connecting them]

Answer (score 1):

Let the two ellipses be

$$
\left \{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    \displaystyle \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} &=& 1 \\
    \displaystyle \frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2} &=& 1
  \end{array}
\right.$$

where $\dfrac{h^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{k^2}{b^2}>4$ for no intersection.

At the minimal distance, the line segment should be normal to both ellipses.

Now considering tangents of the two ellipses with common slope $m$,

$$
\left \{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    y &= &mx \pm \sqrt{a^2 m^2+b^2} \\
    y-k &= &m(x-h) \mp \sqrt{a^2 m^2+b^2}
  \end{array}
\right.$$

The perpendicular distance between two tangents is

$$d=\frac{mh-k\pm 2\sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$

Using the upper case, the local extremum of $d$ as $m$ varying gives the minimal distance.

Comment: Note: This answer seems to assume that that the two ellipses aren't rotated, and are of the same shape and size. It's unclear if this was the intention by OP

Comment: See also another case in my older post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851240/find-theta-and-phi-that-maximize-mid-2ia-sin-theta-2ib-sin-phi-2c1/1853136#1853136).

Comment: Thank you @NgChungTak! I should've been more clear, as @Milten pointed out, that the two ellipses can be different shapes/sizes, but they will not be rotated. It seems your older post you linked to satisfies that. How do I get the start and end points of the line though? I can take the derivative of $d$ with respect to $m$ and set to 0 to find the minimal distance, then plug that $m$ into the tangent line equations, then find the intersections of those tangent lines with their ellipses. Can I solve for $m$ easily?

Comment: Please **modify your question** by including the fact that "the two ellipses can have different semi major and semi minor axes, but they are not rotated" : it is not evident to infer it from your drawing or to read all the comments before reaching this one...

Comment: I updated the question, thanks @JeanMarie